# Checking if selected cell is in specific range

Tags: c#, excel, range, cell

I'm using C# to create a Excel Add-In.

How can I check if selected(or cell represented by a range in code) is in specyfic range. For example how to check if cell $P$5 is in range $A$1:$Z$10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Application.Intersect`, like this (in VBA)

```
Sub TestIntersect()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim TestRange As Range

    Set TestRange = [$A$1:$Z$10]
    Set MyRange = [P5]

    If Not Application.Intersect(MyRange, TestRange) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "the ranges intersect"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, I am adding the C# version (as requested in the question):

```
var myRange = Application.Range["$P$5"];
var testRange = Application.Range["$A$1:$Z$10"];

if (Application.Intersect(myRange, testRange) != null)
{
    // do something 
    
}
```