# how to check if an Excel cell belongs to a range, and its address relative to the Range

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

From my C# application, I am using WorkSheet.UsedRange to find the range of data in a WorkSheet.

I need to check if a specific cell C13 belongs to UsedRange or not; and if it belongs, what is its Row Number & Column Number within the Range.

Example, if the Range starts from Row 10 and Col B, then C13 is Row 4 and Col 2 within the Range.

I found a similar question here:
[Checking if selected cell is in specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767320/checking-if-selected-cell-is-in-specific-range)

The solution given there is Intersect method.

But in C#, Excel.ApplicationClass's Intersect method takes a very high number of parameters, and while I can pass Missing.Value to so many parameters, I want to know if there is an alternate way other than using Intersect method.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello AllSolutions... If you want to check if the cell C13 is in the usedRange could you not simply check the C13 cell before you use getRange? If it contains data then it will be in the usedRange. As far as getting its cell location in relation to the usedRange… that could be a challenge. Is the C13 data unique? If so go thru the usedRange and find its location?

Answer (score 0):

Can this work?

```
    private static string GetRelativeAddress(Range cell, Range range)
    {
        int startRow = range.Row;
        int startColumn = range.Column;
        int endRow = range.Row + range.Rows.Count - 1;
        int endColumn = range.Column + range.Columns.Count - 1;

        if (cell.Row >= startRow && cell.Row <= endRow &&
            cell.Column >= startColumn && cell.Column <= endColumn)
        {
            return $"R{cell.Row - startRow + 1}C{cell.Column - startColumn + 1}";
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
```